# Authentication for controllers.Assets.versioned

Tags: scala, playframework

Before accessing to static resources i want to authenticate user (if there is no session, user won't access to an html file ) in Play Framework.

```
GET      /assets/*file  @controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

In java controller, @Security.Authenticated(...class) annotation is used to make a method accessible.

What do i have to do to limit access to the static resources?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Write a `Filter`, see if the user is accessing assets using `uri`. try authenticating the user in the filter. If auth is successful then allow the user if not just stop the user from accessing the assets resources.

**How do we know user is accessing assets ?**

```
rh.uri.startsWith("/assets")
```

By checking the `uri` he can check if the user is accessing the assets.

If the user is not trying to access the assets just allow him to pass by doing

```
 f(rh)
```

Create a `Filters` singleton in the root folder of the project (this way you do not need to add it to the `application.conf`)

Write the filter and inject the filter into `Filters` which extends `DefaultHttpFilters`.

Here is the complete working code.

```
import akka.stream.Materializer
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.mvc.{Filter, RequestHeader, Result, Results}

import scala.concurrent.Future

@Singleton
class Filters @Inject() (assetsFilter: AssetsFilter) extends DefaultHttpFilters(assetsFilter) {}

object UserAuthHelper {
  def checkUser(rh: RequestHeader): Future[Boolean] = Future.successful(true)
}

@Singleton
class AssetsFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) extends Filter {
  override def apply(f: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    Logger.info(s"uri ${rh.uri}")
    if (rh.uri.startsWith("/assets")) {
      UserAuthHelper.checkUser(rh).flatMap { result =>
        if (result) {
          Logger.info("User authenticated allow him to use assets")
          f(rh)
        } else {
          Logger.info("stop user. user is trying to access assets without auth.")
          Future.successful(Results.Forbidden("I do not know you."))
        }
      }
    } else f(rh)
  }
}
```